# assertEquals works in selenium but not in JAVA

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I made a testcase in selenium which repeats perfectly and then exported it to JAVA /JUnit4 / Webdriver :

```
public void emailInvalid() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/test/contacts.html");
    driver.findElement(By.name("companyName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("companyName")).sendKeys("testcomp");
    driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).sendKeys("45454545");
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("test.ee");
    driver.findElement(By.name("message")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("message")).sendKeys("qwerty");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.submit")).click();
    assertEquals("Not valid email.", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.error.notValidEmail")).getText());
}
```

The test fails in Java because assertEquals can't get the text its looking for. The error message is

> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[Not valid email]> but was:<[]>

Comment: Check that only one element related to such selector exists and it has expected text instantly since it appeared and text is not generated later. Also, make sure this text really located in this element and not in any child element

Comment: @Gadget It's in the element, I think it's because selenium uses clickandWait when clicking on submit but in JAVA it has just click and it doesnt load fast enough so the assertEqual comes empty! I tried below mike88 code but it just timed out.

Comment: I think you mean it worked with Selenium IDE but does not work once you ported it to Selenium WebDriver/Java. You might want to clarify those details in your question.

Comment: You should spent some time investigating why your `.getText()` returns `""`. You might need to add a `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: Please provide html code.... where 'Not valid email' text is displaying..

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the element cannot be found by the css selector and thereby the assertion fails.

Maybe the element is loaded after the assertion is executed or the element is not loaded at all.

Try to wait for the element to be loaded before the assertion using the following code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span.error.notValidEmail")));
assertEquals("Not valid email.", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.error.notValidEmail")).getText());
```

If this is not the case then check again if the selector is correct.
Also check what getText() returns by printing the actual string.

Comment: IF element is not found the ElementNotFoundException is thrown

Answer (score 1):

In most cases your problem would be bad synchronization.
Your element is found but its text is empty.
You can try touse webDriverWait with expecting the stalenessOf, you can change the way an element is located by using its expected text in the locator or you can add very short sleep

Answer (score 1):

Try waiting for the text present and use an assert if the text is located within the specified time interval. 
Also be sure to check the uniqueness of the element using your css locator.

```
public void emailInvalid() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/test/contacts.html");
    driver.findElement(By.name("companyName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("companyName")).sendKeys("testcomp");
    driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).sendKeys("45454545");
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("test.ee");
    driver.findElement(By.name("message")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("message")).sendKeys("qwerty");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.submit")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.error.notValidEmail")));
    assertTrue(waitForTextPresent(driver, By.cssSelector("span.error.notValidEmail"), "Not valid email.", 20));
}

public static boolean waitForTextPresent(WebDriver driver, By locator, String text, int timeOut) {
    int i = 0;
    int WAIT_SLEEP_INTERVAL = 500;
    boolean isTextPresent = false;
    while (!isTextPresent) {
        i = i + 1;
        try{
             Thread.sleep(WAIT_SLEEP_INTERVAL);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //do nothing
        }
        isTextPresent = driver.findElement(locator).getText().contains(text);
        if (i * WAIT_SLEEP_INTERVAL >= timeOut) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Actually you can also do a get text after the line:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.error.notValidEmail")));
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.error.notValidEmail")).getText());
```

And see if you are getting the text that you are looking for. You may not need to use the method `waitForTextPresent` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check what value of baseUrl. Is it equals "http://yousite" or just ".." or so on? Try to debug this method may be Java didn't found correct url. Or use logging and logging baseUrl + "/test/contacts.html". It look like problem with baseUrl.